# scope variable after select file isn't changed its value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to change scope value to file path after select a file.

This is html file

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().showFilePath(this)">
<div>{{filename}}</div>
```

in controller

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('UploadFile', function($scope){
    $scope.filename = 'please upload a file'
    $scope.showFilePath = function(file){
    console.log(file.value)
    $scope.filename = file.value
    console.log($scope.filename)
  }
})
```

Where `console.log($scope.filename)` is showing "C:\fakepath\1m.jpg" but in webpage it still shows "please upload a file"

How can I deal with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have tried this

```
    $scope.showFilePath = function(file) {
     console.log(file.value)
     $scope.filename = file.value
     $timeout(function() {
        $scope.$apply();
     }, 1000)
    }
```

Comment: Ohhh, that works! Thank you :) so we need to wait for a moment for reapply angular scope value, right?